# data de entrada mvc está a mudar o formato quando mudo o idioma do google chrome

Tags: html, mvc, data, datepicker

Tenho um website feito em MVC e tenho um datepicker, quero o formato de data de Portugal (dd-mm-yyyy), funciona quando tenho o google chrome browser em portugues mas quando o coloco em Inglish (USA) ele muda para mm-dd-yyyy e eu não quero isso.

```html
<input id="dateRangeF2" name="dateRangeF2" type="date" value="">
```

Comment: plz mude sua pergunta em portugues

Comment: Tenho um website feito em MVC e tenho um datepicker, quero o formato de data de Portugal (dd-mm-yyyy), funciona quando tenho o google chrome browser em portugues mas quando o coloco em Inglish (USA) ele muda para mm-dd-yyyy e eu não quero isso.

Comment: Sim, edita a sua edita a sua pergunta pra pt-br, se não ela pode ser fechada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia, você pode usar o [Moment JS](https://momentjs.com/) para formatar a data e cada alteração. Ex:

```js
$("input").on("change", function() {
    this.setAttribute(
        "data-date",
        moment(this.value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        .format( this.getAttribute("data-date-format") )
    )
}).trigger("change")
```

```css
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 150px; height: 20px;
    color: white;
}

input:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px; left: 3px;
    content: attr(data-date);
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
}

input::-webkit-datetime-edit, input::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input::-webkit-clear-button {
    display: none;
}

input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3px;
    right: 0;
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.3/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD-MM-YYYY" value="2019-02-20">
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou :)